# Inheritance vs aggregation and "has-a" vs "is-a".

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In my code I find it useful to use mixin-like inheritance to compose objects with different blocks. I have:

```
class Name
{
public:
    typedef int32_t value_type;

public:
    // ctors and dtors
    void set_value(value_type value) { value_ = value; }
    const value_type& value() const { return value_; }

private:
    value_type value_;
};

class NamedObject
{
public:
    void set_name(const Name& name) { name_ = name; }
    const Name& name() const { return name_; }

protected:
    // ctors and dtors

private:
    Name name_;
};
```

And I use this kind of base classes to provide objects with properties with pre-defined non-virtual functionality:

```
class MyObject: public NamedObject, public HasZlevel {
  // functionality that is not connected with NamedObject and HasZLevel
};
```

**So I decide to treat MyObject as "is-a" NamedObject instead of "has-a" Name.**
Z-level and Name are properties that will never change during MyObject instance's lifetime. I prefer this to aggregation because of simplified usage in algorithms that are defined just for NamedObjects, or for objects that have HasZLevel interface, i can pass them via NamedObject* or HasZLevel* and be sure that they will not be deleted or appended due to protected dtors and ctors.

Another option is aggregation:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject(const Name& name): name_(name) {}
    void set_name(const Name& name) { named_->set_name(name) }

    // and so on...

private:
    Name name_;
};
```

To use this I need template algorithm that requires from parameter type to have set_name member function.

Are there any good reasons in my case to abandon my mixin-like design and to use aggregation? Maybe in long-term maintenance and modification?

Comment: Do you use a tool to format your code like that, or just hit the space-bar over and over again?

Comment: @BlueRaja, no it's formatted by hand, I don't use alignment by const or return type every time, but it can be useful

Answer (score 4):

Because [Multiple Inheritance Sucks](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2009/09/23.html).

> Here is why I like duct tape
>   programmers. Sometimes, you’re on a
>   team, and you’re busy banging out the
>   code, and somebody comes up to your
>   desk, coffee mug in hand, and starts
>   rattling on about how if you use
>   multi-threaded COM apartments, your
>   app will be 34% sparklier, and it’s
>   not even that hard, because he’s
>   written a bunch of templates, and all
>   you have to do is multiply-inherit
>   from 17 of his templates, each taking
>   an average of 4 arguments, and you
>   barely even have to write the body of
>   the function. It’s just a gigantic
>   list of multiple-inheritance from
>   different classes and hey, presto,
>   multi-apartment threaded COM. And your
>   eyes are swimming, and you have no
>   friggin’ idea what this frigtard is
>   talking about, but he just won’t go
>   away, and even if he does go away,
>   he’s just going back into his office
>   to write more of his clever classes
>   constructed entirely from multiple
>   inheritance from templates, without a
>   single implementation body at all, and
>   it’s going to crash like crazy and
>   you’re going to get paged at night to
>   come in and try to figure it out
>   because he’ll be at some goddamn
>   “Design Patterns” meetup.
>
> And the duct-tape programmer is not afraid to say, “multiple inheritance sucks. Stop it. Just stop.”

The long and short of it is: will this actually help you ship your code faster? Or will it cost more time than it's worth because you'll be debugging multiply inherited classes and stepping through a gordian knot of superclasses in a debugger when some overridden member function chokes on some other member up the inheritance tree?

And yes, I did just write 'chokes on a member'. Multiple inheritance really is that bad.

Comment: Joel in the next paragraph says that templates sucks, so aggregation and templates are not an option for this kind of view. Thus both of my approaches sucks. But these words are too general, I ask a concrete question to figure out actual weaknesses in my code.

Comment: @Riga: Templates suck? Is he serious?

Comment: @FredOverflow @Riga: [http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/...](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/has-joel-spolsky-jumped-the-shark.html) But, I do agree with him on avoiding multiple inheritance whenever possible *(99% of the time, the correct way to use MI is the way that more recent languages force you to:  via [interface programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260635%28VS.60%29.aspx))*

Comment: @FredOverflow,@Blue please, consider the alternative approach that I've posted as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543288/inheritance-vs-aggregation-and-has-a-vs-is-a-problem/5553603#5553603

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thumb is "use the weakest relation you can". Have a look at: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill06.htm and http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill07.htm

You can use the private inheritance to model "is-implemented-in-term-of" but you should think at the exception safe implication http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/060.htm

I know, I love guru of the week. ;-)

**EDIT**

> I use this kind of base classes to
>   provide objects with properties with
>   pre-defined non-virtual functionality

Why aggregation is better then inheritance:

1) You can hide methods (or change names) with inheritance all the methods are available by default.

2) You can use class with no-virtual destructor (std::string and all stl containers).

3) You can change implementation easily, if you want change the underlying object your interface will be untouched, however if you inherit from a different base class your interface could change.

4) Exception safe (see the third link).

5) Easy to read.

When "private inheritance" is needed:

1) When the class than you want to use is abstract (you cannot use aggregation).

2) When you want to use protected methods.

When "public inheritance" is needed:

1) When you want to access to private methods and data (you shouldn't do that).

In the end, aggregation allows you a better control over your interface. I usually prefer this option. Private inheritance is sometimes the only option, however the cost is a more rigid interface and also consequences on exception safety. I try to avoid using private inheritance as much as possible.

I haven't ever used public inheritance to model "has-a".

Comment: +1 for giving a valid point and not just multiple-inheritance paranoia. However, it would be better if you added the main points from Sutter's articles here and actually established some relation to the specific example.

Comment: thanks for the links, I've read first two of them, but can't find straight connections with my situation, as @Itjax have mentioned, that's why I asked my question here. As for the last article, I usually use noncopyable mixin, so operator= problems don't bother me. There is nothing concrete in examples given there besides that. One problem what I can see clearly is that constructor parameters are need to be passed via base classes ctors to mixins in chain principle. But if you have default ctors in mixins that assign pre-defined undefined values, that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, if you publicly inherit like you're doing here, sometime, somewhere, someone will treat your class as a `NamedObject` or a `HasZlevel` and try to delete by parent pointer, pass it around, etc. And this will probably just not work out too well.

If you want to use a mixin type strategy like this, at least use `private` inheritance, and then `using` the parent methods you need into the public sections of the respective child class(es).

However I wouldn't particularly suggest doing even that. If you use inheritance to represent substitution then your base classes represent an interface, not features. I would say that using composition in this case makes more sense. The entire standard library is based around generic (template) algorithms so I wouldn't work about that. Free-standing template algorithm methods are a great way to extend your code without having to modify your class internals, or even its public interface.

Comment: Deleting through a base-class pointer can (and should) be prevented by declaring a `protected` non-virtual destructor. Other than that - what is a problem in _passing it around_? Why would it not work too well?

Comment: @anatolyg Accidental slicing is the main thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, that's serious enough to consider redesigning. Thanks.

Comment: Accidental slicing can be prevented by making the ctor protected too.

Comment: @anatolyg, @Itjax and what do you think of alternative approach I've posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543288/inheritance-vs-aggregation-and-has-a-vs-is-a-problem/5553603#5553603

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with multiple inheritance is that somebody will try to model a person as inheriting from "arm" and "leg" and then complain that multiple inheritance confused the issue.

Mixins come from the Lisp world, and I've never been convinced that they fit C++ all that well.  However, multiple inheritance itself isn't evil, and can be necessary.  It is very common for something to have an "is-a" relationship with more than one thing.

As a rule of thumb, I try to use only empty base classes, i.e., what Java calls interfaces.  If I need data of any kind in my base classes I have almost always found that my design was as bad as trying to define a person class as inheriting from "arm" and "leg."  There are exceptions, and if you believe you've found one, try writing up a document and asking a few friends to comment on it.  A rule of thumb isn't a formal mathematical proof, but it has been very useful to me.

Comment: thank you for your good examples with arm and leg. As I can see now, I use inheritance from NamedObject instead of from Name for these reasons too. Yes, one can say that it is just a wrapper that do not change logic. Maybe, it's not so clear to me, that is what I'm trying to understand now.

Comment: please see an alternative approach I've posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543288/inheritance-vs-aggregation-and-has-a-vs-is-a-problem/5553603#5553603

Answer (score 1):

As almost everyone said those multi inheritance objects are scary, horrible and useless.

I think you are asking yourself the wrong question or, how do I make sure that my code can be statically checked at compile time.

The first question you should ask is: What details do I need to hide from my implementation decision.

Where are you using these sad objects? What are they modeling?

Comment: I like your approach, that lack of a clear answer is usually a sign of lack of a clean question. I don't accept multiple inheritance phobia by default, so I don't throw away my very handy approach immediately.   I use my objects in algorithms and data structures that i.e. just need to now that object has name. I don't like to use templates as a substitution of duck-typing because we don't have concepts so I can't document my code well in terms of a language. I don't like generalization then it is not needed, passing NamedObject* is much more readable opposite to creating template.

Comment: I try to explain why I think of such objects in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543288/inheritance-vs-aggregation-and-has-a-vs-is-a-problem/5553603#5553603

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to avoid multiple inheritance by transforming my usage pattern to the following:

```
template<class T>
class Named: public T {
  // all for named object
};

template<class T>
struct NamedCompare {
  bool operator<const Named<T>* obj1, const Named<T>* obj2) {
    //...
  }
};

template<class T>
class NamedSet {
  typedef std::set<NamedSet<Named<T>*, NamedCompare> type;
};

bool DoSmthWithFoo(Param1 p1,..., NamedSet<Foo>::type& set);
```

So I can make objects of wanted functionality in a way

```
typedef Named<Featured<Blabla<Foo> >  > NamedFeaturedBlablaFoo;
```

or

```
class NamedFeaturedBlablaFoo: public Named<Featured<Blabla<Foo> >  > {};
```

if I can use default constructor to prevent pollution of compiler logs.

The main advantage that I see - I can divide functionality on different properties and use divided blocks for many classes. Additionally I make somewhat like concepts meaning I explicitly define with what objects I am working in a template functions.

I see one design hole that I inherit from concrete classes, but this is to be explained how it threatens my code actually.
Another problem is hiding of typedefs of Foo class if it is template and I can see no ways to work it around.
This code smells bad...

I can declate NamedCompare and NamedSet just in the same way but without Named usage, just call name() from T. This will work and I can use it in standalone algorithms. I think it's much better than these mixins.

Comment: Simply put, I think you're overthinking the problem and getting an overcomplicated solution as the result.  There isn't a need, especially at the beginning of a project, to solve every possible problem the most generic way.  First, solve the problem with the vanilla aspects of the language, then if you see the same pattern cropping up, solve those problems with more generic approaches.

Comment: @Max, you're absolutely right. Talking about the subject, I think the last paragraph of this answer is my solution. All that inheritance is very dubious in my situation. Lets make things simpler.